# MongoDB $or query in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

The mongodb $or operator works as intended outside of a meteorjs context:

```
db.users.find({$or: [{email: 'some@mail.com'},{city: 'atlanta'}]});
```

I get results for any document that has email some@mail.com or city of atlanta.

The same query in Meteor syntax doesn't yield the same results :

```
Users = new Meteor.Collection("users");
Users.find({$or: [{email: 'some@mail.com'},{city: 'atlanta'}]});
```

I've read the meteor docs - http://docs.meteor.com/#find - and since it doesn't say anything about it, I'm assuming it should run just the same as a mongodb 1.6+ instance?

Comment: What's the diff with the new results?

Comment: SomeKittens, the Cursor returned all my records, while fetched returned the number of correct matches. For my testing, I only had 6 documents in my collection, and find() returned all 6, fetch matched 3 correctly.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`find` returns a cursor object.  You need to use a [`fetch`](http://docs.meteor.com/#fetch) to get the array of values. Try:

```
console.log(Users.find({$or: [{email: 'some@mail.com'},{city: 'atlanta'}]}).fetch());
```

Comment: why does it behave like this?

Comment: @HaikalNashuha Read all about cursors here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861558/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-database-cursor

Comment: What does $or stand for? - sorry newbe

Comment: @haemse $or is not an abbreviation, it is a name of a logical operator that returns true if either or both operands is true and returns false otherwise. It is common to see it in any language and it behaves the same way everywhere.