# Android sqlite INER JOIN return array

Tags: android, arrays, database, sqlite

I am using sqlite for android and I want a function that returns an array with all the objects that fulfill a condition. I explain:

I have two tables:
Peliculas

```
private static final String CREATE_PELICULAS_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + PELICULAS_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_PELICULA_ID + " LONG PRIMARY KEY, "
                + KEY_PELICULA_PORTADA + " BLOB NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_PELICULA_DIRECTOR + "TEXT NOT NULL"
                + ")";
```

Pendientes

```
private static final String CREATE_PENDIENTES_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + PENDIENTES_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_PENDIENTES_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + KEY_PEN_IDSerieOPeli + " LONG NOT NULL );";
```

In the database "Pendientes"  are the IDs of the movies (películas) that have been added as pending (pendientes). I want a function that through an inner join returns an array with all that movies.

The query with the inner join I think is something like this:

```
private final String QUERY= "SELECT * FROM PELICULAS_TABLE a INNER JOIN PENDIENTES_TABLE b WHERE a.KEY_PELICULA_ID=b.KEY_PEN_IDSerieOPeli";
```

I guess I would have to use rawQuery too, but I don't know for sure.

But I don't know how I can return all of that movies (items of peliculas) in an array.

Comment: if you used rawQuery() you'd get a Cursor. You'd use this Cursor to create a List (or an array) with the resulting data. Do you know how to work with a Cursor?

Comment: Not too much but I can try.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866631/how-does-cursor-work-in-android) is helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return a Cursor using the rawQuery method or alternately using the recommended query method.

So you could have either

```
Cursor csr = db.rawQuery(QUERY,null);
```

or

```
Cursor csr = db.query("PELICULAS_TABLE a INNER JOIN PENDIENTES_TABLE b",null,"a.KEY_PELICULA_ID=b.KEY_PEN_IDSerieOPeli",null,null,null,null);
```

[SQLiteDatabase - query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Your method (function) could be :-

```
public ArrayList<Movies> getAllMoviesThatFulfillCondition() {

    ArrayList<Movies> rv = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor csr = db.query("PELICULAS_TABLE a INNER JOIN PENDIENTES_TABLE b",null,"a.KEY_PELICULA_ID=b.KEY_PEN_IDSerieOPeli",null,null,null,null);
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        long current_SerieOPeli = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_PEN_IDSerieOPeli));
        long current_Pelicula_ID = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_PELICULA_ID));
        byte[] current_Pelicula_Portada = csr.getBlob(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_PELICULA_PORTADA));
        String current_Pelicula_Director = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_PELICULA_DIRECTOR));

    rv.add(new Movie(??????????));
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

- **NOTES**
- `?????????` would be according to however you construct the **Movie** object (assuming that's what you mean when you say ***the objects***  i.e. Movie is the object).
- If any column names in the resultant cursor are not unique (e.g. say KEY_PELICULA_ID resolves to the String **ID**  and also KEY_PENDIENTES_ID resolvs to the String "ID") The you would have to differentiate them using an **AS** clause.
- It may be that your condition is really how the tables should be joined. If so then you could use the **ON** clause in the **JOIN** clause. e.g.  `private final String QUERY= "SELECT * FROM PELICULAS_TABLE INNER JOIN PENDIENTES_TABLE ON " + PELICULAS_TABLE + "." + KEY_PELICULA_ID + "=" + PENDIENTES_TABLE + "." +   KEY_PEN_IDSerieOPeli;`
- **NOTE** the above is in-principle code, it has not been tested not sytax checked so it may contain errors.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for all of the explanations, I understood everything. Thank you ver much sir!