# Distinction between database cursors and cursors used in psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, cursor, psycopg2

I may be confused but that's exactly why I ask. Can a program using `psycopg2` execute commands against the database without using a cursor? Every [example](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial) I've ever seen uses `cur = conn.cursor()` and then an execute statement like `cur.execute("""SELECT datname from pg_database""")`

My question is can `SELECT datname from pg_database` be done without cur?

Is the psycopg2 idea of a cursor the same idea of the actual [database cursor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/plpgsql-cursors.html) i.e. is there a 1-1 relationship?

After read 
[What are the benefits of using database cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861558/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-database-cursor) I was a bit confused as they seem to speak as if cursors aren't nescecary (but I guess when directly interacting with the db through e.g. pgadmin they are).

Comment: It is the same word, the same concept, but it are different things.

Comment: @wildplasser please speak clearly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That form is part of the Python DB-API. It's written to accommodate databases where one connection can multiplex multiple statements with open result sets, and to emulate that where the database does not support it directly.

Rather than have two ways of doing the same thing - with a cursor, or without - the DB-API expects database drivers always use a cursor object, even if they're only ever keeping one result set open at once. The interface is the same for client-side and database-side cursors.

By default `psycopg2`'s cursors are client-side. Its "cursors" aren't really anything to do with a database cursor. When you run a statement, the result set (if any) is read into the `psycopg2` cursor object. You can then iterate over it client-side. In that sense it is a cursor, in that you can read the next row, scroll the cursor, etc.

You *can* [ask `psycopg2` to use true database-side cursors](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors). It doesn't use PostgreSQL's wire protocol cursor support (unfortunately), instead doing the cursors at the SQL level with `DECLARE`, `FETCH`, etc statements.  Server-side cursors don't require lots of memory on the client (or server) and they can deliver the first results to the application before the whole result set has been transferred. However, by default they're forward-only, unlike psycopg2's in-memory client-side cursors, and they consume database resources until they are released.

Both have different advantages and disadvantages.