# Why aren't cursors optional in mysqlclient?

Tags: python, mysql, database-cursor

I'm quite new to Python and Flask, and while working through the examples, couldn't help noticing cursors. Before this I programmed in PHP, where I never needed cursors. So I got to wondering: What are cursors and why are they used so much in these code examples?

But no matter where I turned, I saw no clear verdict and lots of warnings:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(databases)#Disadvantages_of_cursors): "Fetching a row from the cursor may result in a network round trip each time", and "Cursors allocate resources on the server, such as locks, packages, processes, and temporary storage."
- [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861558/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-database-cursor): See the answer by AndreasT.
- [The Island of Misfit Cursors](http://explainextended.com/2009/06/28/the-island-of-misfit-cursors/): "A good developer is never reluctant to use a tool only because it's often misused by others."

And to top it all, I learned that **MySQL does NOT support cursors**!

It looks like the only code that doesn't use cursors in the `mysqlclient` library is the `_msql` module, and the author repeatedly warns not to use it for compatibility reasons: "If you want to write applications which are portable across databases, use MySQLdb, and avoid using this module directly."

Well, I hope I have explained and supported my dilemma sufficiently well. Here are two big questions troubling me:

1. Since MySQL doesn't support cursors, what's the whole point of building the entire thing on a Cursor class hierarchy?
2. Why aren't cursors optional in `mysqlclient`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are confusing database-engine level cursors and Python db-api cursors. The second ones only exists at the Python code level and are not necessarily tied to database-level ones.

At the Python level, cursors are a way to encapsulate a query and it's results. This abstraction level allow to have a simple, usable and *common* api for different vendors. Whether the actual implementation for a given vendor relies on database-level cursors or not is a totally different problem.

To make a long story short: there are two distinct concepts here:

1. database (server) cursors, a feature that exists in some but not all SQL engines
2. db api (client) cursors (as defined in [pep 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)), which are used to execute a query and eventually fetch the results.

db api cursors are named so because they conceptually have some similarity with database cursors but are technically **totally unrelated**.

As to why mysqlclient works this way, it's plain simple: it implements [pep 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), which is the community-defined API for Python SQL databases clients.

Comment: I don't think I'm confusing the issue. My question title specifically mentions the `mysqlclient` library, which is built on `MySQLdb` and is expected to support MySQL only. And I'm not sure I agree with the common API thing. Why would a library designer force cursors upon me?  What if I don't want to use cursors in some situations, even if the underlying engine supports them? These should be optional (which is my question no. 2).

Comment: Yes your are confusing issues. The `Cursor` class in `mysqlclient` is NOT a database level cursor ("server cursor"), so your whole point about *database level* cursors is just moot. And no one forces you to use *database* level cursors on DB engines that support them (cf psycopg's doc http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors for an exemple).

Comment: "so your whole point about database level cursors is just moot" - Just when was my whole point about database-level cursors? In fact, the link you shared is moot because this question is specific to MySQL. But let me rephrase the original question in a way I think you'll understand: Since MySQL has no database-level cursors, why does `mysqlclient`, a library dedicated to MySQL, masquerade as a Cursor implementation? Is is plain laziness? Or does the library do some sort of behind-the-scenes stuff? Please respond only if you can answer in the context of `mysqlclient`. I don't want an argument.

Comment: I updated my answer in a way I dare hope you might be able to understand. Well, at least if you genuinely want to understand, that is...

Comment: Perfect! Adding PEP249 clears all doubts. I wish you had provided that detail sooner. :-)

Comment: Sorry I didn't, I thought the reference to "Python db api" was enough of a clue... My bad.