# What is an SQLite Android cursor, conceptually?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Is the SQLite Android Cursor conceptually the same as an ArrayList containing all the rows resulting from a query ?

If not, how does it differ ?

For example, what happens if

1. I make a query `Q` and get Cursor `C`
2. Modify the DB (such that the `Q` query executed in step 1, now would return a different result )

Will the cursor `C` obtained in step 1 reflect the changes made to the DB in step 2 ?

What is the purpose of the Cursor ? Why not just return an ArrayList containing all the rows ?

Comment: "Will the cursor C obtained in step 1 reflect the changes made to the DB in step 2 ?" -- no, unless your result set is over 1MB, at which point the story gets complicated. "What is the purpose of the Cursor ?" -- it represents a 2-dimensional result set of some sort of query, against a SQLite database, a `ContentProvider`, etc.

Comment: "Why not just return an ArrayList containing all the rows ?" -- questions of the form "why did Developer X do Thing Y?" are not well-suited for Stack Overflow, as only Developer X can answer definitively. That being said, `Cursor` is an interface with several implementations. Some of those implementations have limits on how much data can be loaded at a time, notably the IPC limits imposed on a `ContentProvider`. The `Cursor` API allows Google to handle those differences internally while maintaining a consistent API across implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the comments !

Comment: this seem to partially answer the purpose of the cursor : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861558/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-database-cursor