# update slow for large rows but ok in chunks

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-update, rollback

So i am trying to update say 1 million rows in a 10 million row table.

I have an index on Y.

One mass update seemingly never finishes. I am thinking this is due to maintaining the data in tempdb incase the transaction needs to rollback, and the tempdb might not be big enough and needs to page to disk etc. Whereas the chunks loop only needs to do this for 50k rows at a time.

Just after others thoughts, correct me if I am wrong, I am from an Oracle background so not entirely sure what the rollback segment equivalent is

```
update  X
set   Y = 0
where Y  is null
```

but doing in chunks of 50000 finishes in a minute

```
declare @i int=1
while @i > 0
begin
    update top (50000) X
    set   Y = 0
    where Y  is null

    set @i = @@ROWCOUNT
end
```

Comment: i love it how someone down votes it but has no feedback to give. what has become of stack overflow. you cant even ask questions now, and also why i stopped answering them too

Comment: Does the table in question get massive amounts of queries against it? It could be that the cursor is faster because the big set based update cant aquire the lock it needs and is simply put on hold. Ive had something similar happen on a database which was under very heavy write load.

Comment: Also, i think the down vote might be because your tsql is broken and more pseudocode than real code.

Comment: @JensB What about that syntax is not valid?

Comment: I would have answered if  not for the negative comment

Comment: that is actual tsql code

Answer (score 0):

This might be a case where the database is under such heavy load (or the server is so underpowered) that the set based operation is to heavy and simply cant complete because it cant get a lock or requires to much resources all at once.

By design a cursor works on a smaller subset of data, this in theory should be slower but might not be in your particular case.

From here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10013070/937131

> A cursor can save you time - because you don't need to wait for the
>   processing and download of your complete recordset It will save you
>   memory, both on the server and on the client because they don't have
>   to dedicate a big chunk of memory to resultsets
>
> Consistency: Using a cursor, you do (usually) not operate on a
>   consistent snapshot of the data, but on a row. So your
>   concurrency/consistency/isolation guarantees drop from the whole
>   database (ACID) to only one row. You can usually inform your DBMS what
>   level of concurrency you want, but if you are too nitpicky (locking
>   the complete table you are in), you will throw away many of the
>   resource savings on the server side.

Comment: Nolock does not apply to an update.  It is ignored.  Check MSDN.

Comment: @Paparazzi duly noted. I found another source that stated otherwise,  but msdn clearly states as you noted it will do nothing on an update.
"READUNCOMMITTED and NOLOCK cannot be specified for tables modified by insert, update, or delete operations." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table