# Convert mongoDB AggregationCursor response into array format for 500K+ records is taking lot of time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Sorry to ask repeated questions, but I referred to too many articles but was not able to solve my use case.

**Technology used**

1. NodeJs
2. mongodb (MongoClient ) librabry with NodeJs

I have tried two approaches as below:

```
  const records = client
    .db(mongodbDATABASE)
    .collection('subscriptions')
    .aggregate(pipeline)
    .toArray()
```

2. ```
   const records = client
     .db(mongodbDATABASE)
     .collection('subscriptions')
     .aggregate(pipeline)

   while (await records.hasNext()) {
     const subscription = await records.next()
     //TO DO with subscriptions
   }
   ```

I run aggregate pipeline query in compass and NoSQL-booster and I'm getting responses very quick **(200ms) with 500K records** but whenever I'm trying to convert the aggregate result to array format by using the above methods(.toArray(), .hasNext() ) it's almost taking **3-4 minutes**.

Could you please help on it how I can convert this AggregationCursor to array format without much impacting the performance?

Answer (score 0):

the [cursor pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10013070) is not going to fetch all data at once, hence it is returning in only 200ms. to fetch 500k rows is going to take a while no matter what approach you take on the client, as this will require a lot of work for the database server.

Comment: Thank you @Dave for your input, I'm thinking to create MongoDB Atlas Data lake pipeline and putting data on S3 and query via Athena