# automatic closing of result-set in Java SQL

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Consider the following code

```
ResultSet rs = null;
Statement st = null;
try {
  //do somehting
 } catch (Exception e){
  //do something
 } finally {
     if(st != null){
       try {
       st.close();
       } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("Exception while closing statement: " + e);
       }
    }
 }
```

The question is that when we close the statement, will it close the result set as well or do we need to explicitly close the result set like this

```
if(rs != null){
   try {
   rs.close();
   } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Exception while closing result set: " + e);
   }
}
```

I thought that closing the statement will automatically close the result set, but FindBugs throws the following warning if I don't explicitly close the result set

> This method may fail to clean up java.sql.ResultSet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if one exists, is also closed.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103938/resultset-not-closed-when-connection-closed) and [this](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=41036) shows that Oracle may have problems and you might have to explicitly close the `ResultSet`. But again, as per the Javadocs, this shouldn't be an issue. Hence, the warning,maybe.

Comment: any ideas then why FindBugs reports a warning for this one ?

Comment: It might be legacy. IIRC, closing ResultSets when the Statement is closed wasn't always in the JDBC spec (a looong time ago, like 1.2ish). There are probably drivers out there that don't do it properly.

Answer (score 3):

You can't count on the ResultSet being closed automatically, it depends on the driver implementation and how compliant it is. The best policy is to close the ResultSet explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

When you close the statement or connection, all it's children should be closed too by default.