# Best design pattern to close database connection when exception occurs

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm new to Java (I'm using Java 6). I've been using the below design pattern for all my Java POJOs and servlets to access an Oracle 11G database via GlassFish 3.1.2 web server.

I'm getting an intermittent database error (ORA-12519) when all available processes (or sessions, not sure what the difference is) are consumed, leading me to think somehow the processes are not being released by the application.

Looking at the design pattern below, is there a better way to make sure that the JDBC connection to the database is released in the event of an exception? For example, should I also place the `if ( conn != null) conn.close();` code INSIDE the catch block? Or, is there a better design pattern? Thanks in advance for any comments/hints.

```
public String MyFunction() throws Exception {     

    Connection conn;
    CallableStatement cs;

  try {

      Context context = new InitialContext();
      DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("jdbc/MyPool");
      conn = ds.getConnection();        

      cs = conn.prepareCall( "{call my_sproc (?)}" );

      cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);

      cs.execute();

      String outParam = cs.getString(1); 

      if ( conn != null )  // close connection
         conn.close();

  } catch (Exception e) {
      outParam = "an error occurred";
  }
    return outparam;
}
```

Comment: Note that it may also be good practice to close resultsets and statements. Here's a useful link (see Stefan Schweizer's reply in the link for good design pattern): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103938/resultset-not-closed-when-connection-closed

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
if ( conn != null )  // close connection
         conn.close();
```

At this line `conn` *cannot* be null. The most popular pattern, up until Java 6 is:

```
Connection conn = null;
try {
   // initialize connection
   // use connection 
} catch {
  // handle exception
} finally {
  if (conn != null) {
     try { conn.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* handle close exception, quite usually ignore */ } 
     }
}
```

With **Java 7** this will become less cumbersome with its [try-with-resource](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/trywithresources-401775.html) construct. The above code can change to the much shorter

```
try (Connection conn  = createConnection()) {
    // use connection 
} catch {
    // handle exception
}
// close is not required to be called explicitly
```

Comment: Thanks Miserable Variable, when you say "up until Java 6" do you mean "up to and including Java 6" (that's what I'm using)? I assume so. Also, when you say "quite usually ignored", are you refering to only the `try...catch` within the finally block (that is, the `if (conn != null) conn.close();` is always there, right?)? Why do people usually ignore handling the exception in the finally block for closing the connection?

Comment: Yes, exceptions from `connection.close()` are often ignored or at most logged but not handled in any other way:) I don't know why; I have never actually seen a close throwing an exception.

Comment: Just to be clear, since finally executes no matter what, I don't need to close the connection inside the try block right? I can just close the connection once place in the code, which is in the finally block. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, as I showed in my template, connections are typically only closed in finally.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`finally`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) block always to free up resources.

> The finally block always executes when the try block exits. This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs.

```
  try {

      Context context = new InitialContext();
      DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("jdbc/MyPool");
      conn = ds.getConnection();        

      cs = conn.prepareCall( "{call my_sproc (?)}" );

      cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);

      cs.execute();

      String outParam = cs.getString(1); 


  } catch (Exception e) {
      outParam = "an error occurred";
  }
 finally {
       conn.close();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Kazekage, Will the `conn.close()` line of code in the finally block give an error if the connection hasn't been open yet or any other reason? If so, shouldn't I use that `if (conn!=null)` statement above in the finally block?

Comment: If you suspect that `conn.close()` will again give an error, surround that with a `try catch finally` as well.

Comment: @ggkmath yes you need to test for `conn != null`; it can be null if `ds.getConnection()` throws exception. And whether you suspect or not, you need to put `close()` in `try/catch/finally`; else the method has to incloude it in its `throws` clause which is not good.

Answer (score 2):

java se 7 supports the try-with-resources feature. that generates the finally for you. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

the finally block will close the resources alocated in the try. like you were using the keyword using in c#

however the user is using java se6 ... See the options of other users :)

IMPORTANT: Statements used should be closed too.

Comment: I didn't read but the user Miserable Variable talked about try-with-resources too.

Comment: I will confirm that in 1 min but i guess you need to close the statements

Comment: Doesn't seem universal. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103938/resultset-not-closed-when-connection-closed  and http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread%5Fid=41036

Comment: I was wrong. The apidocs for [`Connection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close()) do not say that closing a `Connection` closes its `Statements`; but note that closing [`Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close()) *is* required to close the `ResultSets`

Comment: @MiserableVariable The JDBC spec specifies that Statements are closed when the connection is closed (section 9.4.4.1 of the JDBC 4.1 spec). Also the JavaDoc of `Connection.close()` states "Releases this Connection object's database and JDBC resources immediately" JDBC Resources are any objects created from a connection (ie Statements)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thank you for that clarification but the javadocs is not as explicit about closing `Statements` when closing `Connection` as it is about closing `ResultSets` when closing `Statements`

Comment: @MiserableVariable True, the documentation (and the spec) does sometimes lack detail or clarity, it is even worse when you try to implement a JDBC driver ;)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer another more elegant way than:

```
} finally {
  if (conn != null) {
     try {
         conn.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         /* handle close exception, quite usually ignore */
     } 
  }
}
```

You could use DbUtils.closeQuietly: http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/DbUtils.html