# new jre7 try block resources

Tags: java, try-catch, java-7

If I do something like

```
    try (
        Connection conn = Database.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = ? LIMIT 1");
    ) {
        ps.setString(1, "hello world");
        ResultSet results = ps.executeQuery();
        if(results.next()) {
            // blah
        }
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Will the ResultSet still be closed when the PreparedStatement is closed, or will I still have to explicitly close the ResultSet also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [javax.sql.Statement.close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29) method's JavaDoc:

> Note:When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if one exists, is also closed.

So, answering your question - yes, `ResultSet` will be automatically closed in your case, because related `Statement` is closed in `try-with-resources` block.

However, please note that explicitly closing `ResultSet`s is a good practice which is recommended to follow, so your modified code following good practices would look like:

```
try (
    Connection conn = Database.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = prepareStatement(conn, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = ? LIMIT 1", param);
    ResultSet results = ps.executeQuery();
) {        
    if(results.next()) {
        // blah
    }
} catch(SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

private static PreparedStatement prepareStatement(Connection connection, String sql, String param) throws SQLException {
    final PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1, param);
    return ps;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn' there in the signature of prepareStatement method be an exception thrown, I think SQLException?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/103938/642706) for other reasons to always close your ResultSet explicitly (or have it closed with a try-with-resources syntax). Design limitations and bugs all too commonly found in JDBC drivers, connection pools, and databases can all cause problems with unclosed ResultSets.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Always</strike> As a good practice, try to close your <strike>ResultSets and</strike> PreparedStatements. In a finally block. <strike>Every single time</strike> , managing exceptions, so you won't leave resources unattended (is a common source of leaks).

Unless you inject them to the method, hence the calling method probably needs them.

EDIT: Stand corrected. If resultset was created as try-with-resource, will die with your PS.

Comment: "In a finally block. Every single time." Not true. The point of `try-with-resources` is so you don't have to do that, however it doesn't apply to the `ResultSet` in his case.