# PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS and Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, prepared-statement

I am trying to fix this code to update my log table in a mysql database 5.6
Do you know how to retrieve the primary key from the database and assign it to my id variable (Log)

Thanks

Log model without getters and setters

```
private int id;
private Timestamp date;
private String userName;
private String event;
private String message;
private String audioPath;
```

Database Table

```
CREATE TABLE `log` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`date` datetime(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00.00',
`user_name` char(60) NOT NULL,
`event` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`message` text NOT NULL,
`audio_path` varchar(250) NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Add Entry Log

```
@Override
public int addEntry(Log log) throws SQLException {

    Connection conn = Database.getInstance().getConnection();

    PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement(
            "insert into log ( id, date, user_name, event, message, audio_path) "
            + "values (?,?,?,?,?,?)", 
            PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

    p.setInt(1, p.getGeneratedKeys()); //error
    p.setTimestamp(2, log.getDate());
    p.setString(3, log.getUserName());
    p.setString(4, log.getEvent());
    p.setString(5, log.getMessage());
    p.setString(6, log.getAudioPath());

    int updated = p.executeUpdate();


    p.close();

    return updated;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `id` is declared as `AUTO_INCREMENT` you don't need to mention it in the query:

```
String sql = "insert into log ( date, user_name, event, message, audio_path) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
```

In this way MySQL will automatically generate new id.

Then, you should do this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql, RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)
ps.setTimestamp(1, log.getDate());
// ...
ps.setString(5, log.getAudioPath());

int updated = ps.executeUpdate();

ResultSet generatedKeysResultSet = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
// first row of this set will contain generated keys
// in our case it will contain only one row and only one column - generated id
generatedKeysResultSet.next(); // executing next() method to navigate to first row of generated keys (like with any other result set)
long id = generatedKeysResultSet.getLong(1); // since our row contains only one column we won't miss with the column index :)

log.setId(id);

return updated;
```

Besides that, after you try and get working example I would really recommend to correctly close MySQL `Connection` and `PreparedStatement` using JDBC. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320196/new-jre7-try-block-resources/11320538#11320538) on how to correctly create and close resources.

Hope this helps

Comment: Auto Key values generated are accessible after they are inserted successfully. Hence one should only call `getGeneratedKeys()` post `executeUpdate()`.

Comment: @Yura Thanks a lot it did what I wanted. I had just to change the id from int to long. Should I change my database table accordingly?

Comment: @QuentinTanioartino I'm glad it helped! I would say to use just `int` in database instead of `int(11)` unless you need special logic with digits like in following Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634104/what-is-the-size-of-column-of-int11-in-mysql-in-bytes